# Adding data from my database to infowindow in Google API V3

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3

i have a probleme to my infowindow, i can't show my title and description on it.
 The relation between my data base and google api is good because i can show my marker on the map but when i click on it there is nothing in the infowindow.
Here's my code:

```
function createMarker(lat, lng, titre, description, adresse){var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng,map: map,title: titre});
contentString =                         
     '<div class="descritpion"  >'+'<a>(titre)</a>'+''
'</div>';
var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString,});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infobulle.open(map, marker);});}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of how I do it (though I usually also hold all the markers in an array so they can be cleared, or updated as a group). Also, I'm assuming your syntax around `titre` was wrong, and have corrected to to be what I thought you wanted to achieve.

```
var MyInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'Loading...'});
function createMarker(lat, lng, titre, description, adresse){
    var point=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point,map: map});
    marker.html='<div class="descritpion"  ><a>('+titre+')</a></div>';
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        MyInfoWindow.setContent(this.html);
        MyInfoWindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```